# Assigning a promise result to a variable in nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, promise

```
let data =  users.find({})
                    .toArray()
                    .then((result) => {
                    state.response.end(JSON.stringify({
                            message: result
                        }));
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        state.response.end(JSON.stringify({
                            error:  err.message,
                        }));
                        log.error(failed to process the request: ", err);
                    });


if(!!data){

return collage.find({_id: params._id}).toArray()
                    .then((collages: any[]) => {
                        if (!!collages) {
                            return //some more code
                        }
                    })
                    .then(() => {
                        return university.find({_id: params._id}).toArray()
                    })
                    .then((user: any[]) => {
                        if (!!user) {
                            return   //some more code
                        }
                    })
                    .then(() => {
                        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
                        response.end(JSON.stringify({status: " Request processed."}));
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                       response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
                        response.end(JSON.stringify({status: "error",  + err.message}));
                    });


}
```

return all promises result at once like

```
return {
collage:collages,
university:users
}
```

Here i am fetching data from multiple collections using promise(no async and await). i want to retrieve the data from users collections first then from other collections. code inside if condition returning first without waiting users collections results. is it write way to do that ? or?

Comment: Why can't you use async/await?

Comment: Please complete your question with what the undeclared variables are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are new to Nodejs never mind, Before beginning to code, you should understand synchronous code vs asynchronous code. Your code is not getting executed synchronously. Read this out:

https://codeforgeek.com/asynchronous-programming-in-node-js/

https://javascript.info/async

Also, learn callbacks, promises, and async-await

**Note:** I am not checking logic here I am just guiding you with the flow, Please check all condition by yourself

You can use `async-await`

```
    try {
    let data = await users.find({}).toArray()

    if(check proper condition here){
      let collages = await collage.find({_id: params._id}).toArray()
      so and so.....
    }
   catch(err) {

   }
```

==============================Using Promises==========================

```
 let final_result =  {};
 users.find({}).toArray()
                .then((result) => {
                 let data = result;
                  state.response.end(JSON.stringify({
                        message: result
                    }));
                  if(check for condition)
                   return collage.find({_id: params._id}).toArray();
                }).then(function(collages){

                   final_result.collages = collages;
                    return university.find({_id: params._id}).toArray()

                 }).then((users) => {
                  final_result.users= users
                  so and so ......

                }).catch((err) => {
                    state.response.end(JSON.stringify({
                        error:  err.message,
                    }));
                    log.error(failed to process the request: ", err);
                });
```

Comment: is there any way without async-await ?

Comment: you can chain promises

Comment: then where i have to customize the output i want combine both table results at the end and return like ` return {table1: collage,table2:universities }`

Answer (score 0):

`data` is not defined when you access it a second time. That's how asynchronous code works, there's [a guide on it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous) if you're not familiar with the concept, but basically `.toArray()` **is a promise that resolves to a value**, it is not **a value**.

Here's what you could do:

```
// using .then
users.find({}).toArray().then(data => {
  // data is defined, do something with it
});

// using async/await
const data = await users.find({}).toArray();
```